# Coldfusion: cfchart: clips or crops my series marker at the top of the graph

Tags: coldfusion, cfchart

I am plotting a line chart. (aka Frame chart)
My series markers are begin clipped or cropped when the value is the maximum.
I have data from 0.0 to 10.0.  When the value is 10, it does not show the complete marker.  I really don't want to have to set the scale to 11.  (make no sense as the values can never be greater than 10.0 and looks really bad)

Is there a setting in the xml style that I am missing or is there a setting on the server that will increase the plot area so this does not happen?  I am using both the built in markers and custom markers but it makes no difference.  Both get cut-off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda a what the ...
Although the chart is only a 2d flat line chart, change this to a 3d chart with a Zero rotation.  Do this in the .xml style file either created by hand or using "webcharts.bat" to launch the chart editor and create the file.  Do both items below

- Remove *is3D="false"* (or set to true i.e. *is3D="true"*) as part of the "frameChart" tag.  *This is usual the second line of the xml file.*
- and add *xDepth="0" yDepth="0* to the "frame" tag.  *This is frequently the third line of the file.*
  Note: no "is3d" and addition of "xDepth" and "yDepth".

> ```
> <frameChart autoAdjust="false" font="Arial-12-bold">
>   <frame xDepth="0" yDepth="0" type="None" outline="black" leftAxisPlacement="Back" isHGridVisible="false" isHStripVisible="true" >
>   <background minColor="#FDFEF6"/>
> </frame>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you played at all with the chart builder?  Basic info [here](http://www.fusioncube.net/index.php/customizing-your-cfchart-results).  It's been a while since I used it, but I believe you can set things like margins and padding for the chart in this.  I recall it being relatively easy to use, once you get a little practice.

Comment: Yes, in fact that is what I used to create the original chart.  Unfortunately, the problem occurs either when I am using the "built in" styles or using the XML file created with the chart builder. It does not matter, nor does it matter if I am using the "built in" makers or custom pics. <thanks for replying though>